# Copy Common Columns to separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I tried the below code to copy entire column from one page to other page.

I've common header that is June scattered in the sheet, I want to copy only the columns, with header name as "June" in the separate sheet one after the other.

EG if Col A, C,L,M has column header as June, then on the next sheet these should be only copied as A,B,C,D.

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select 
June = WorksheetFunction.Match("Description", Rows("1:1"), 0) 

Sheets("sheet1").Columns(June).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Comment: use the `Find` function in row 1, set a `Range`, and if `Find` is successful, get the `Column` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following might help:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim headerRng As Range, cel As Range, copyRng As Range
    Dim lastCol As Long, col As Long

    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")      'Sheet1
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")     'Sheet2

    lastCol = srcSht.Cells(1, srcSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    'last column of Sheet1

    With srcSht
        For Each cel In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastCol))  'loop through each header name in Sheet1
            If cel = "June" Then                            'check header is "June"
                If copyRng Is Nothing Then                  'assign range to copy
                    Set copyRng = .Columns(cel.Column)
                Else
                    Set copyRng = Union(copyRng, .Columns(cel.Column))
                End If
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
    copyRng.Copy destSht.Range("A1")                'copy and paste desired columns
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice + you can use `With srcSht` to shorten and clean up your code

Comment: It shows an error in  copyRng.Copy destSht.Range("A1").

Comment: Run time error – 91
Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: @NehaKohli - Can you debug and check `copyRng.address`

Comment: @NehaKohli - In which row do you have headers in `Sheet1`? And make sure you have at least one column with header June.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got that.. how to do.. can you help ?

Comment: Row 1 I have the header as June

Comment: you can try the working solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371362/excel-merge-worksheets-with-different-structure/45372405#45372405  let me know if this is of help.

Comment: @NehaKohli - Put a breakpoint at the error line then execute the code and in immediate window type `?copyRng.address` See [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) for how to debug.

Comment: I think its in infinite loop, its not coming out of Next Cell

Comment: @NehaKohli - If you are getting error at line `copyRng.Copy destSht.Range("A1")` then it is obvious that it is coming out of loop. Still check the value of `lastCol`

Comment: Sorry, the lastCol is 12

Comment: @NehaKohli - Put the break point at `copyRng.Copy destSht.Range("A1")` this line. For loop will be executed for 16379 times and check `copyRng.Address`

Comment: Done, now ? It says, "Run time error – 91 Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: @NehaKohli - Check `copyRng.Address`

Comment: I don't know how to check copyRng.Address

Comment: @NehaKohli - Put cursor at error line `copyRng.Copy destSht.Range("A1")`  and press `F9` to put break point. Then press `F5` to run the code. Then type `?copyRng.Address` in immediate window and press enter and check the value. Press `Ctrl+G` to open immediate window.

Comment: I am not getting any immediate window where I can place ?copyRng.Address

Comment: @NehaKohli - Press Ctrl+G to get immediate window in VBA Editor.

Comment: after entering ?copyRng.Address in the immediate window

Comment: @NehaKohli - Probably there's nothing in `copyRng`. Are you sure there is a column with header "June"  in row 1 with no spaces around?

Comment: Yes.. I am very much sure.

Comment: Hey.. it works.. Thank you very much..I must say you are most patient person .

Comment: Thanks a lot Mrig :)

Comment: @NehaKohli - What was the issue?

Comment: June was written in capital.. excel is case sensitive as well

Comment: @NehaKohli - If you want code to do non case sensitive match, you can use `If UCase(cel) = "JUNE" Then` instead of `If cel = "June" Then`